# CID? - Where is the picture when sent from MAC: outlook?

Tags: email, outlook, incoming-email, mac-os-x

When sending an e-mail from outlook on Windows OS it works just as expected. However, when sending it from outlook on a MAC OS it doesn't. The item gets created but the body will have an CID. If the image is attached it doesn't even appear.

The following is an ***announcements list*** configured to receive e-mail:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?
Thank You for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This had nothing to do with SharePoint. The problem was on exchange...